# Can typescript be debug in a terminal?

Tags: typescript

I have been doing some google searching for this question, but all the articles I find, talk about debugging using VsCode or some other IDE.

I would like to know if there some tool like Python's PUDB or PDB for typescript, that could let you debug directly from the terminal where your code is running.

Edit: I'm talking about backend applications, no web apps.

Comment: Your browser's console?  Questions asking for tool recommendations are off-topic on SO.

Comment: Typescript compiles to javascript. Look for a CLI javascript debugger. They do exist,

Comment: @Evert thanks I will take a look at those.

Comment: @Amy Sorry I didn't myself quite clear. I'm talking about micro-services running on the backend, no web apps.

Answer (score 0):

For backend apps writtend in TS, you can use the [`ts-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) or [`ts-node-dev`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node-dev) package

`ts-node-dev` is more suited to dev environments for watching files and real time debugging.

I hope this helps you out!

Comment: Oh I see, the problem is to debug at runtime.

Comment: That said, ts-node-dev could still be handy with a JS CLI debugger as it "abstracts" the compilation to JS at runtime.